# GraphQL Query for Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, graphql, mongodb-realm

I am using graphql from the last few days. I am using query to excess some data from my mongodb data base. The query is

`query {try{sentences{tokens { index word }}}}`

It is giving me all the data from my data base. Now when I am trying to use some filter in my query, I am facing error. If any one can me any idea or solution about my mistake it will be helpful.[image]

[image]

I tried same `(word: "such")` , in query, try and sentences also. But facing same error. Tried to do greater, equal and different query with find and filter.

***schema

[image]

Comment: please add the `objectType` and schema in your question

Comment: Hello @Chandan, I added the schema in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try after changing query as below:**

```
{
    query {
        try {
            sentences {
                tokens(query: { word: "such"}) {
                    word
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am tried earlier this command. But still facing same error after using this also.

{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"query\" on field \"tokens\" of type \"TrySentence\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 20
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: After using this query, facing same issue. 


"message": "Cannot query field \"query\" on type \"Query\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 5